How to retrieve Google Doc first few page Only via API
I'm currently working on a proof of concept (POC) where I need to retrieve only the first 5 pages of a document. Retrieving all pages would exceed Salesforce's heap size limit. While all content is important, my focus is on validating the content available within the initial pages.
I'm utilizing the Google API:
https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/{documentId}

Despite searching extensively, I haven't been able to find a solution. Google's Bot suggested using the suggestionsViewMode parameter with values INDEXES_ONLY or FIRST_FOUR_PAGES_ONLY, but these options aren't present in the latest API version.
API document : https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get

I think that unfortunately, in the current stage, your goal retrieve only the first 5 pages of a document cannot be directly achieved using Google Docs API. For example, if each page is separated by the page break, it can be achieved. But, if it's not, as an approach, I think that several elements can be retrieved from body.content[] of "Method: documents.get". At that time, for example, it might be required to also check inlineObjects, positionedObjects, and so on. But, I cannot know your expected values. So, I can propose only abstract methodology. I apologize for this situation.

@Tanaike I can use page break if that will help.

Thank you for replying. About I can use page break if that will help.,  I think that when the page break is used as the separation of each page, the first 5 pages can be obtained from body.content[].
